# Isekai manga where the main character is weak and meets strong blonde knight girl

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character (MC) gets isekaied to a demon forest and somehow makes it out. He then he meets a strong female knight that he can't understand, because they don't speak the same language, so she takes him to a priestess who casts a spell that lets him understand them.

That's all in the first chapter but as the story goes on, the knight and MC spend more time together and the female knight is worried that the MC is a bad guy, because of how he lies and has a scary look on his face when he gets serious.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Also it would help if you broke this into sentences and paragraphs.

Comment: hey, my bad in not that good with punctuation. i read this in manga park i think and it was like a few moths ago. i defiantly remember most of the story i just dont remember the title

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

***[It's Sudden, but I Came to Another World! But I Hope to Live Safely](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/rtjq40d/isekai-demo-bunan-ni-ikitai-shoukougun)*** seems like a good match.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-demo-bunan-ni-ikitai-shoukougun):

> "Understanding" is stronger than a sword! There is no magic without weapons! But, this is the story of a man who wishes to live safely! A man stands alone on a mountain full of plants and creatures that he never knew nor saw before. He goes down the mountain by avoiding encounters with bears, slimes and bandits, and is hauled into prison the second he reaches a large city. On top of that, a pretty female knight called Illias manages to break him out and whisks him away to a church. What would a female knight need with a yellow-bellied pacifist? And when will this hair-raising day end already?!

The main character (MC) wakes up in a forest in another world and is attacked by a bear, which is in turn attacked by a slime, inadvertently saving him.

The MC has no apparent powers or weapons, so he sneaks through the forest to avoid being seen until he finally emerges from it and spies a kingdom. However, no one there can understand him, and he ends up being thrown in prison.

He's then visited by a blonde, female knight who puts him in a sack and carries him to a church. At the church, there's a woman who is able to cast a spell that allows them to understand one another.

That's all in the first chapter. In subsequent chapters, the knight does begin to distrust the MC after seeing the way he speaks and behaves in certain situations.

[image]

[image]